# Where to find the time interval for a key combination to work?

Tags: key-bindings

the key combination `dw` is to delete a word. I've also defined my own key combination, e.g. `<leader>j` to move to a window below. My question is how much time is left between the first and second keystroke to make the combination work? Is there some place I can customize this setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting you are looking for is `ttimeoutlen` and `timeoutlen`.  `timeoutlen` sets the time (in milliseconds) that is waited for mapped sequence or key code to be completed.  If you want a different timeout length for key codes, you can set `ttimeoutlen`.  If `ttimeoutlen` is set to anything but `-1`, `timeoutlen` is used to set the timeout of key mappings.

See `:help 'ttimeoutlen'`