# ^O (Ctrl+O) works slowly

Tags: key-bindings

In my system, `<C-o>` works really slowly compared to `<C-i>` or `<C-p>`. Is it just my experience or is there a subtle reason behind it?

Is this in any way related to `ttimeoutlen`? I saw `ttimeoutlen` mentionned in a [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/12779/17250) about slow (user defined) key bindings but I am not sure it is the same problem.

Thank you

Comment: First you can check the result of `:map <C-o>` if it returns one (or several lines) with `<c-o>` followed by other(s) character(s) then setting `ttimeout`, `timeout`, `ttimeoutlen` and `timeoutlen` differently could be useful for you. In this case you could read [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2503/1841) and you *should* read the doc [`:h 'ttimeout'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27ttimeout%27) which gives a table describing how to configure these settings.

Comment: @statox I think it is not mapped.  `:map` lists only two lines:
n  gx            <Plug>NetrwBrowseX
n  <Plug>NetrwBrowseX * :call netrw#NetrwBrowseX(expand("<cWORD>"),0)<CR>

Comment: Then the timeout settings shouldn't be a problem here. Have you tried to start vim without a vimrc to check if the problem comes from your configurations? See [How do I debug my vimrc?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841)

Comment: <C-o> is called in normal mode, so :nmap may also apply. Check for that one also.

Comment: @Vitor Actually `:map` lists the mappings in every mode so `:nmap` shouldn't show more mappings than `:map`

Comment: Ups, you are correct!